# Apply Impulse Not Working Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've been developing a game in which colored dots (SpriteKitShapeNodes) fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. Before, I was using SpriteKit gravity to get the dots to fall down, but I've decided I wanted to improve the falling aspect and decided to use impulses instead. For some odd reason, the dots are not receiving the impulses or something else. The dots do not move at all. Points of interest are in the "Change[color]" functions.

```
var Green = SKShapeNode()
var Red = SKShapeNode()
var Yellow = SKShapeNode()
var Purple = SKShapeNode()
var Blue = SKShapeNode()
var Green2 = SKShapeNode()
var Red2 = SKShapeNode()
var Yellow2 = SKShapeNode()
var Purple2 = SKShapeNode()
var Blue2 = SKShapeNode()
//var sparkEmitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Animations/Spark")
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var ScoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
var HighScoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
var RestartLabel:SKLabelNode!
var BackButton:SKSpriteNode!
var π = M_PI
var clickPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var hitPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var jumpPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var pointPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var pop2Player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var Background = SKSpriteNode()
var startTimer = NSTimer()


var CustomWidth: UInt32 = UInt32()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */



    //Add this back in if you want the color needed to change every minute
    //var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    CustomWidth = UInt32(frame.size.width - 300)
    print("Normal Width Is: \(frame.size.width)")
    print("Other Width Is: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)")
    print("Middle is: \(self.size.width / 2)")

    self.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    self.size.height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    print("Width is now: \(self.size.width)")


    Background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "images/edit/background")
    Background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 )
    Background.zPosition = -1.0

    self.addChild(Background)

    //Physics
    //self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector( dx: 0.0, dy: -0.2 )
    //self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    print(physicsWorld.speed)

    setupCircles()
    spawnCircles()

    changeColorNeeded()


func restartGame() {

    //self.physicsWorld.speed = 1.0
    spawnCircles()
    changeColorNeeded()
    removeRestartLabel()
    addBackScoreLabels()
    //self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector( dx: 0.0, dy: -0.2 )
}

func setupCircles() {

    Green = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) // Size of Circle
    Green.position.y = frame.size.height
    Green.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    Green.glowWidth = 1.0
    Green.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    Green.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Green.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
    Green.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Green.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Green.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Green.name = "Enemy"

    Red = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) // Size of Circle
    Red.position.y = frame.size.height
    Red.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    Red.glowWidth = 1.0
    Red.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    Red.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Red.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
    Red.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Red.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Red.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Red.name = "Enemy"

    Blue = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) // Size of Circle
    Blue.position.y = frame.size.height
    Blue.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    Blue.glowWidth = 1.0
    Blue.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    Blue.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Blue.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
    Blue.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Blue.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Blue.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Blue.name = "Enemy"

    Yellow = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) // Size of Circle
    Yellow.position.y = frame.size.height
    Yellow.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    Yellow.glowWidth = 1.0
    Yellow.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    Yellow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Yellow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
    Yellow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Yellow.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Yellow.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Yellow.name = "Enemy"

    Purple = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) // Size of Circle
    Purple.position.y = frame.size.height
    Purple.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    Purple.glowWidth = 1.0
    Purple.fillColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
    Purple.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
    Purple.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
    Purple.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Purple.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.Bar
    Purple.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Purple.name = "Enemy"

    self.addChild(Green)
    self.addChild(Red)
    self.addChild(Blue)
    self.addChild(Yellow)
    self.addChild(Purple)
}



func changeGreen(){

    if IsPaused == false{

    Green.position.y = frame.size.height + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)

    var PositionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(radius) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * radius)))


    Green.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        while Green.containsPoint(Red.position) || Green.containsPoint(Blue.position) || Green.containsPoint(Yellow.position) || Green.containsPoint(Purple.position) {
            print("Overlap Detected")
            changeGreen()

        }
        let randomX: CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        print("RandomX For Impulse = \(randomX)")
        self.Green.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 0.1))
    }

}

func changeRed(){

    if IsPaused == false{

    Red.position.y = frame.size.height + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)

    var PositionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(radius) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * radius)))


    Red.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        while Red.containsPoint(Blue.position) || Red.containsPoint(Yellow.position) || Red.containsPoint(Green.position) || Red.containsPoint(Purple.position) {
            print("Overlap Detected")
            changeRed()

        }
        let randomX: CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        print("RandomX For Impulse = \(randomX)")
        self.Red.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 0.1))
    }
}

func changeBlue()   {

    if IsPaused == false{

    Blue.position.y = frame.size.height + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)

    var PositionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(radius) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * radius)))

    Blue.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        while Blue.containsPoint(Red.position) || Blue.containsPoint(Yellow.position) || Blue.containsPoint(Green.position) || Blue.containsPoint(Purple.position) {
            print("Overlap Detected")
            changeBlue()

        }
        let randomX: CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        print("RandomX For Impulse = \(randomX)")
        print("Applying Impulse")
        self.Blue.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 0.1))
    }
}

func changeYellow() {

    if IsPaused == false{

    Yellow.position.y = frame.size.height  + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)

    var PositionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(radius) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * radius)))


    Yellow.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        while Yellow.containsPoint(Red.position) || Yellow.containsPoint(Blue.position) || Yellow.containsPoint(Green.position) || Yellow.containsPoint(Purple.position) {
            print("Overlap Detected")
            changeYellow()

        }
        let randomX: CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        print("RandomX For Impulse = \(randomX)")
        self.Yellow.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 0.1))
    }
}

func changePurple() {

    if IsPaused == false{

    Purple.position.y = frame.size.height + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)

    var PositionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(radius) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * radius)))


    Purple.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        while Purple.containsPoint(Red.position) || Purple.containsPoint(Blue.position) || Purple.containsPoint(Yellow.position) || Purple.containsPoint(Green.position) {
            print("Overlap Detected")
            changePurple()

        }
        let randomX: CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        print("RandomX For Impulse = \(randomX)")
        self.Purple.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 0.1))
    }
}

func spawnCircles() {

    changeRed()
    changeBlue()
    changeGreen()
    changeYellow()
    changePurple()
}

func randomYPos() -> Double{

    var rand = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(0.10) + UInt32(0.8)))

    return rand
}

func changeColorNeeded() -> SKColor {

    colorNeeded = randomColor()
    return self.colorNeeded

}


func randomColor() -> SKColor{
    var colors: [SKColor] = [SKColor.yellowColor(),     SKColor.blueColor(), SKColor.greenColor(), SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.purpleColor()]

    var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 0)

    return colors[rand]
}
```

Comment: You should definitely follow naming conventions, especially here on StackOverflow (because of wrong highlighting), like @crashoverride777 pointed in his answer (and yeah, 0.1 probably has no effect on your bodies).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see anything obviously wrong with your code. 
Did you try to increase the value of the impulse?. 0.1 seems quite low. Also if you want them to move down you need to make it a negative value.

It is also a good idea if you follow the swift programming guide. Your properties should not start with capital letters, only classes, protocols and structs should. This makes you code also harder to read on SO because it is marked blue but shouldn't.

Comment: I have tried increasing the values. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: That's strange. Did you try a few 100s?